# Facebook offline wall posting

Tags: facebook

I do have website for Restaraunt which has facebook registration module for the users to register. There are two kinds of user for my website, one is normal registered user and second user is Facebook Registered user. This seems to work correctly upto this moment.In the website, all the users are allowed to post their own review about hotels,favorites etc.

I need a way for automatic sharing of reviews, likes and favourites to the users Facebook wall in the Facebook website by using there Fb details(Fbid) that i have stored in my database. Each the reviews need to be posted to the FB wall using his/her own fb-id without fb login. Is there is any php-Facebook plugin /JSSDK to meet this requirement?

I have used the following lines of library codes, but nothing happend yet now.

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$api_key = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
$secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$name = 'Publish feed code example';
$id='100001948358224';
$name_href = 'http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=44721';
$caption = 'A simple code caption text';
$description = 'The new Facebook.streamPublish code to pop up a publish feed form';
$img_1 = 'http://www.applications.junkieyard.com/fbfgsfy/images/smileys/smiley-09-05.png';
$img_1_href = 'http://apps.facebook.com/fbfgsfy/profile.php';
$action_links_text = 'Facebook?';
$action_links_href = 'http://www.facebook.com/';
$attachment = array('name' => $name, 'href' => $name_href, 'caption' => $caption, 'description' => $description, 'media' => array(array('type' => 'image', 'src' => $img_1, 'href' => $img_1_href)));
$action_links = array(array('text' => $action_links_text, 'href' => $action_links_href));
if ($id) {

    $target_id = $id;
    ?>
    <script>
        var message = "";
        var attachment = <?=json_encode($attachment)?>;
        var action_links = <?=json_encode($action_links)?>;
        var target_id = <?=$target_id?>;
        alert(Facebook.streamPublish(message, attachment, action_links, target_id));
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

?>

Comment: You just need the `publish_stream` permission along with the user id `uid`. If you have these piece of info, it's an easy task.

Answer (score 2):

offline_access is no longer used in facebook, the new way is the Expiration Time of the TOKEN through New Endpoint 
read more at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to request the `publish_stream` and `offline_access` [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the user to post on their wall when their session is not active.

To post on their wall programmatically, use the [feed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) method of `FB.ui`

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Restaurant App',
        link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp',
        caption: 'Check out my review',
        description: 'The most awesome restaurant ever.',
        message: 'Check out this awesome app'
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.post_id);
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            console.log('Post was published.');
        } else {
            console.log('Post was not published.');
        }
    }
    );
```

To see the above code in action, check it out on [the demo app FBRell](http://fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed)

Comment: Thanks for your response. is there any full detailed code with clear specification about the offline access.

Comment: @Anandhan You have to include it in your permissions list when you're requesting permissions. See [this sample code](http://fbrell.com/auth/extended-permissions).

Comment: i have used the above piece of code to accomplish it, but still don't have much permissions to do so.Can you please provide me someother working examples. i don't want the users to relogin in the site, i need to use there existing details(FB-id) for posting on his FB wall.